# XMPP chat api timeout

Tags: facebook, api, timeout, xmpp, chat

Im trying to do a web-based facebook chat via php, i read the docs and find a good sample to start.

I'm using the x-facebook-platform authentication method.
I can log in and send messages thanks to this but the problem is that the authentication process takes a lot of time and sometimes i get a timeout.

Do you guys could tell me why ?
I find that the script becomes really slow after it sends the response to facebook challenge.

Thanks you =).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing webbased, you might have better luck with javascript.  Personally I like strophe.js, however there are many options to choose from.  This page has 9 javascript clients:

http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/